# return Observable.fromPromise throws an error

Tags: redux-observable

I'm using redux-observable and my epic has the following code

```
return action$.ofType('SEARCH').mergeMap((action) =>
        return Observable.fromPromise(axios.get(SEARCHURL)).map(result => {
            const filteredStoresAsActions = result.data.stores.map(store => ({
                type: 'SEARCH_RESULTS',
                searchText: action.SearchText.toLowerCase().trim(),
                store
            }));
            // Create the interval to emit an item every second
            return Observable.interval(1000)
                .take(filteredStoresAsActions.length).map(t => filteredStoresAsActions[t]);           
        });      
);
```

Now when I run the code I get the following error

**PromiseObservable.js?7552:76 Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.**

I'm not sure why this error is being thrown and how to fix it.  Plus another question I have is if I return Observable.fromPromise then who interprets this and how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

The outer `.map()` should return an action object, not an Observable. Try using `.concatMap()` instead:

```js
return action$.ofType('SEARCH').mergeMap((action) =>
  return Observable.fromPromise(axios.get(SEARCHURL)).concatMap(result => {
    const filteredStoresAsActions = result.data.stores.map(store => ({
      type: 'SEARCH_RESULTS',
      searchText: action.SearchText.toLowerCase().trim(),
      store
    }));

    // Create the interval to emit an item every second
    return Observable.interval(1000)
      .take(filteredStoresAsActions.length).map(t => filteredStoresAsActions[t]);           
  });      
);
```